# ObjectiveFlickr Setup Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, flickr

I'm looking to implement Flickr in my iPhone app with ObjectiveFlickr. I'm using Xcode 4 and am trying to follow this part of the instructions:

"On your app target, open the info window (using Get Info on the target), then in the General tab, add ObjectiveFlickr (library) to Direct Dependencies."
https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr

How do I "Get Info" on my target in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure those instructions are quite accurate, but if you want to add a dependency, here's how:

Tap the project in the project navigator, tap your target, then open the Build Phases tab.

You will be able to access the dependency in the top section by tapping the "+"

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried that, but just wanted to make sure "Target Dependencies" and "Direct Dependencies" were the same thing. I think the instructions provided at the link are outdated (probably for Xcode 3.x).  Nevertheless, thanks for your answer.